# Product image wont load and dropwon wont populate

Tags: magento2

My product images keep uploading forever and dropdowns won't populate in the Product page.

Here it is: http://dosanto.com.br/loja/camiseta-omolu-obaluaie.html

Comment: your product name creates an issue for `breadcrumbs`. It stops javascript.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: I figured it out. Rewrote the names without the quotation mark. Tsk. @kunj

Comment: Welcome, happy to help you, let me put it in answer then accept it so it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove quotation mark or change your product name. because `""` mark creating the issue in `breadcrumbs` rendering and stopping other scripts to run.